# Normalizing my data without knowing population estimates

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, statistics, data-science, data-analysis

I am currently working on a deep learning project. My input is of the shape (20,938). I'm trying to normalize the data and then scale them between 0 and 1. Now my dataset contains around 53k examples.

It is computationally expensive for me to read every data point and calculate the overall min, max, mean and standard deviation.

Does anyone know a better approach ?

Comment: Calculating mean/std can be done on-the-fly (without reading all data points into memory). Maybe ask a question about that? It's not going to get better if you do full training instead of simple statistics.

Comment: (And if you decide to make another question, please show us the code you currently use to read your inputs and calculate the statistics.)

Comment: You can add a Batch Normalization layer as the first layer in your network and let the NN learn the mean/std parameters during training. On another note: training neural networks is a lot more computationally expensive than computing means and standard deviations.